# Did I do this right? $x-y=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, graphing-functions

So, to make a graph for the equation $x-y=5$. I plugged in values for $x$ for example I used $0$ and $1$, For $0$ I plugged it in for $x$ and did this.

$0-y=5$ Then subtracted $0$ from both sides, which got me $-y =5$ I then divided $-y$ by both sides and got $-5$

Did I do this right? Am I supposed to divide y by both sides?

Comment: If you get $-y = 5$, you should divide both sides by $-1$ to obtain $y = -5$.  In this case, you can easily find another point on the line if you let $y = 0$.

Comment: Oh! So I got it! :D

Comment: You got the right answer for the wrong reason.  You should not divide by $-y$.  You should divide by $-1$, which is the implicit coefficient of $y$ in the expression $-y$ since $-y = -1 \cdot y$.

Comment: I can't believe I actually figured it out all by myself!

Comment: Oh ok! I gotta remember to use the coefficient, thank you!!!

Comment: Can you find another point on the line?  That would allow you to graph the line.  In this case, the easiest choice would be to set $y = 0$.

Comment: Yes, for $0$ i got $-5$

Comment: If $x = 0$, then $y = -5$.  What happens if $y = 0$?

Comment: Um... $5$ right? Plug in $0$ for y, then subtract that from both sides, then divide by $1$.

Comment: Yes, if $y = 0$, then $x = 5$.  Therefore, you have found the points $(0, -5)$ and $(5, 0)$ are on the line.  You can obtain the graph of the line by plotting those points, then drawing the line that passes through those points.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!